# system.reflection.targetinvocationexception SQLite

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, orm

I use an ORM to manage my SQLite database in my C# project. This is it : https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

It's really hopefull but I can't use SELECT Query. When I run this :

```
var transacts = db.Table<Transact>();
```

I get in return this exception : `system.reflection.targetinvocationexception` on this line :

```
public void SetValue(object obj, object val)
{
    _prop.SetValue(obj, val, null);
}
```

The complete message is :
`system.reflection.targetinvocationexception exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`

And I have my constructors :

```
public Transact()
    : base()
{
    Console.WriteLine("yo");
}

public Transact(int subCategoryIdT, string descriptionT, 
    DateTime dateT, double amountT, int ownerIdT)
{
    db.CreateTable<Transact>();
    SubCategoryId = subCategoryIdT;
    Description = descriptionT;
    Date = dateT;
    Amount = amountT;
    OwnerId = ownerIdT;
    db.Insert(this);
    Console.WriteLine("I'm here !! I'm " + description + ".");

}
```

Can you see where my mistakes are?

The content of the innerException :

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Busy
  at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x000c6] in /Users/gautier/Documents/Dev/csharp/bumget/bumget/SQLite.cs:2087
  at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Execute (System.String query, System.Object[] args) [0x00046] in /Users/gautier/Documents/Dev/csharp/bumget/bumget/SQLite.cs:627
  at bumget.Transact.set_OwnerId (Int32 value) [0x0003a] in /Users/gautier/Documents/Dev/csharp/bumget/bumget/Transact.cs:49
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

My Transact class :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using SQLite;

namespace bumget
{
    public class Transact
    {
        private int ownerId;
        private int subCategoryId;
        private string description;
        private DateTime date;
        private double amount;
        private int expense;

        private SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection (Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "bumget.db3"));

        public Transact () : base() {
        }

        public Transact (int subCategoryIdT,string descriptionT,DateTime dateT,double amountT,int ownerIdT, int expenseT)
        {
            db.CreateTable<Transact>();
            SubCategoryId = subCategoryIdT;
            Description = descriptionT;
            Date = dateT;
            Amount = amountT;
            OwnerId = ownerIdT;
            Expense = expenseT;
            db.Insert (this);
            Console.WriteLine("I'm here !! I'm "+description+".");

        }

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public int OwnerId
        {
            get{
                return ownerId;
            }
            set{
                ownerId = value;
                db.Execute("UPDATE Transact SET OwnerId = ? WHERE Id = ?",OwnerId,Id);
            }

        }

        public int Expense
        {
            get{
                return expense;
            }
            set{
                expense = value;
                db.Execute("UPDATE Transact SET Expense = ? WHERE Id = ?",Expense,Id);
            }

        }

        public int SubCategoryId
        {
            get {
                return subCategoryId;
            }
            set{
                subCategoryId = value;
                db.Execute("UPDATE Transact SET SubCategoryId = ? WHERE Id = ?",SubCategoryId,Id);
            }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get{
                return description;
            }
            set{
                description = value;
                db.Execute("UPDATE Transact SET Description = ? WHERE Id = ?",Description,Id);
            }
        }

        public DateTime Date
        {
            get{
                return date;
            }
            set{
                date = value;
                db.Execute("UPDATE Transact SET Date = ? WHERE Id = ?",Date,Id);
            }
        }

        public double Amount
        {
            get{
                return amount;
            }
            set{
                amount = value;
                db.Execute("UPDATE Transact SET Amount = ? WHERE Id = ?",Amount,Id);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Utilisateur :" + OwnerId + ", Montant: " + Amount + "CAN$, Date: " + Date.ToString () + ", Category : " + SubCategoryId + ", Description : " + Description + ", Owner = "+OwnerId + ", expense = "+Expense;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the message of the exception? What data are you passing into the `_prop.SetValue` method?

Comment: @gunr2171 I have edited my post and I'm passing a null object + an integer (this is what I see when I print obj and val)

Comment: If `obj` is null, this wouldn't work. You can't assign a property value to a null object.

Comment: obj is not null in fact I got this : `User :0, Montant: 0CAN$, Date: 01/01/0001 00:00:00, Category : 0, Description : , Owner = 0, expense = False` instead of `User :12, Montant: 12,06CAN$, Date: 22/09/2014 13:05:03, Category : 1, Description : Beers, Owner = 12, expense = True`

Comment: i've edited with the content of the innerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no matter how good OOP is, the WP implementations of SQLite aren't always working as intended, and often you better of just write the SQL query yourself.

Having said that, do you have your properties properly set? In your DB you have the field `Owner` instead of `OwnerId`, so you need to assign the attribute `[Column(Name="Owner")]` to your `OwnerId` property

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have the field OwnerId in my DB, for example this command works fine : `db.Execute("UPDATE Transact SET OwnerId = ? WHERE Id = ?",OwnerId,Id)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is simply the mapping of your OwnerId property. In your SELECT method above, you wrote that the output is:

User :0, Montant: 0CAN$, Date: 01/01/0001 00:00:00, Category : 0, Description : , Owner = 0, expense = False

In this case, I don't see an OwnerId, only an Owner field. But, you know, seeing your C# data model and your table creation SQL query would be extremely handy when answering SQL based questions.

Comment: `public override string ToString()
  {
   return "User :" + OwnerId + ", Montant: " + Amount + "CAN$, Date: " + Date.ToString () + ", Category : " + SubCategoryId + ", Description : " + Description + ", Owner = "+OwnerId + ", expense = "+Expense;
  }` That's why you see Owner and not OwnerId...

Comment: I see... Well what I said still holds: your exception obviously shows set_OwnerId in the path, so it doesn't have a problem before that. Can you update your main post with your whole Transact class and the CREATE TABLE query in your database?

Comment: done. But the table is automatically created by the ORM. Thanks for your help.

Comment: System.Exception: Busy

Your database is in use while your UPDATE is called. When you read from your database, you set the values of your newly instantiated Transact instances. This calls the setters, which calls more SQL queries. Your simple Table<Transact>() query this way calls hundreds of update queries. Remove those and move them over to a function.

Comment: Ok thanks ! But if I move my UPDATE from the setters how can I call them when I do something like `MyTransact.OwnerId = 2` to upadate my database ?

Comment: Well... You can optionally create another property for it, set it up with the [Column] tag, and use [Ignore] to ignore your properties that you are using inside your app.
private int owner;
[Ignore]
public int Owner{get{return owner;}set{owner=value; UpdateTable(this);}
[Column()]
public int OwnerId{get{return owner;}set{owner=value}}

Or just make a function to do it and update it externally.

Comment: Thanks but with this solution I must duplicate all my attributes. I thinked to create a Synchronize function instead. What do you think ?

Comment: Well, that's what I do :)

Comment: Haha sorry no problem :)